# SQLite, MySQL or Both for Android Application

Tags: java, android, mysql, relational

I'm in the process of designing an Android application right now.

I understand SQLite works on the phone device within the file structure. However I'm not sure if it's practical for our use.

If I'm wanting to store data that's available to all users (i.e. if someone updates their profile, it can be seen by all other users), can that be done using SQLite somehow? Or must we use a client-server model such as MySQL?

Is it practical to store user-specific information using SQLite and public information using MySQL?

Thank you

Comment: public information?? do you want some db info available to all android users? then you have to do that on server side by sending out some response to your server..

Comment: Yes public as in information to all users of the application.

Comment: Let's say the SQLite is a local storage but you can sync it with a remote service
and make it public. It means you will make a remote service public for everybody to see the 
changes on a local phone/db. Practical to store a public information elsewhere what is public e.g. a service which will provide this info for everybody :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is a Client-Server Architecture, store the data in your central server and get a copy of the working data on the phone. MySQL and SQLite don't share everything but it's close. Read the documentation on SQLite and you will see.
SQLite can't serve files like MySQL if that's your question via the network. You'll have to write that on your own. I suggest making a webservice.

Comment: What do you mean by a webservice? I understand you'll need to use HTTP requests via php scripting to send data to the android phone. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Mount a webservice on a server and let android devices consume from that. Read into SOAP RPC , Webservices, you'll get the idea. Connecting directly to the MySQL database is just a bad idea.

Comment: Just to give an update, we ended up using your suggestion and completed the app. It worked great!

Answer (score 1):

If you want info to be available to all users you need a client-server model such as MySQL.

If you use SQL Lite, the only possible way to update that info without requesting it from a server is to make an Update on the application (not doable).

---

Don't forget that you'll require internet ON for these types of applications.

Comment: Thank you that's a huge help. Exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

you  mean all users going to use a single phone, probably not, the reason for recommending sqlite database for android is that its the lightweight, non memory eater and thus best suitable to mobile phones. Sqlite database can be used in phone while at server side we can use any. The only thing is use a method like sending xml request to server from phone, where server will  send respond as xml or json, while the phone parse the xml and use the data in it. this is how online apps works in mobile phones..... ya ofcourse use mysql at server side and do the communication using as request -  response yes the client-server.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it practical to store user-specific information using SQL Lite and public information using MySQL?

Yes, This is exactly what I'm doing with my app. It's a very common practice. I am storing information in a MySql db stored on a server that all users can read from. They can pull specific information to the device. From there I have a class in the app that stores information that they've selected within a SQLite db. You'll easily be able to add information to the MySql db on the server that all users can view.

Answer (score 0):

yeah i think the model you are proposing should have no problem. Even i'm using a model something similar to what you are saying. I store some information on local sqlite db and majority of information in mysql db. For sending data from android device to mysql db you will have to write a mysql scipt on a page and android device will hit that page with the help of http request. You can send your data in that http request